# Showing other products with my website link

Tags: seo, web-development

I have a website named [Innvokraft](https://www.innovkraft.com/) which is a single-page website. When I try to find the website using the site [link](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:https://www.innovkraft.com/) I got the other products links as shown below

[Link 1](http://www.innovkraft.com/Twistshake-tetilla-Tetinas-w1012/)

[Link 2](http://www.innovkraft.com/gas-Pink-Fairies-TShirt-w405857/)

and you can see when the site checked in for index ranking.

This is the [image] where products are shown with my website link

Please let me know how to remove the links from my website?

Comment: Where are those pages coming from? Previous website? Old sitemap? Since they are all sending 404 error Google should remove them quickly.

Comment: @gael those pages are not from old website or sitemap. We have generated a new site map for that

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have/had a WordPress on your server and Google is indexing it.

[image]

Perhaps you could redirect all those pages to your homepage to make it easyer for Google to understand and more user friendly if someone find one of those results in a search.

If on apache server, you could add this directive to `.htaccess` file at the root of your website.

```
RewriteEngine on
#redirect all subpages to the homepage
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  / [R=301,L]
```

Now since they are all giving a 404 error, Google should deindex them quickly.

If not you will have to ask Google to deindex them: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663419

Comment: there is a blog on my website that uses WordPress